# E: Package 'libavcodec-extra-53' has no installation candidate

Tags: 14.04, vlc, ffmpeg

How can I install libavcodec-extra-53 on ubuntu 14.04?

When I use the following command:

```
root@sana:/home/sana/topology# sudo apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53
```

I receive the following message:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libavcodec-extra-53 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  libav-tools:i386 libav-tools

E: Package 'libavcodec-extra-53' has no installation candidate
```

Comment: `libavcodec-extra-53` is not included in "old-releases.ubuntu" http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/liba/libav/ ... You can get it at https://packages.debian.org/wheezy/libavcodec-extra-53 ... → e.g. amd64 http://security.debian.org/debian-security/pool/updates/main/liba/libav/libavcodec-extra-53_0.8.21-0+deb7u1_amd64.deb ... ("oldoldstable Debian Wheezy").

Comment: You are after either the meta package `libavcodec-extra` or the package `libavcodec-extra-54`. Let me know if this is what you are after and I will create a formal answer...